# Tesseract OCR string manipulation issue

Tags: c#, string, tesseract

I am hoping someone can help me witch this issue I am new to using Tesseract OCR so please bear with me. I created a simple code which allows me to extract text from an image. This works fine

Code Below :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            StringBuilder concatenatedString = new StringBuilder();

            var image = new Bitmap("1.jpg");
            var ocr = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.TesseractAndCube);
            var page = ocr.Process(image);
           list.Add(page.GetText());
           
            foreach (string how in list)
             {
                concatenatedString.Append(how);
                // Console.WriteLine(how);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(concatenatedString);
        }
```

I can get an output, however the trouble I am having is that no matter what I do I can’t seem to merge the output into one line. The output I get is below.

output :

```
16:29:02 SIN: LE1005 Rec: 000375 User2001
07/01/2020 _ I 1463

  


The program '[30388] ocr_image.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

This is what my output looks like multiple lines including blank ones. I have tried things like `join` and `concat` however it just doesn’t seem to do it.

Comment: `Join` or `Concat` are useful for string arrays but tesseract returns only one string variable with include escape characters. I'm cleaning the output with Replace method for similar cases. Did you try it?

Comment: Hi yeah i tried using `string.Replace()` however that didnt work either

Comment: How did you, Can you write the your `Replace("\n")` code line? By the way, you want to only one row, don't you?

Comment: omg i had the slash the wrong way round... feel really stupid right now